# MySQL Joins. match two conditions in two columns

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I am trying to fetch data from the 2 tables using joins. But I don't know how to do it. I have read about joins but it wasn't making any sense since I am new.

I have two tables.

```
 Playgrounds           Inspection 

   id   u_id          id    playground_id
   1    2              1     1
   2    2              2     2
```

In **playgrounds** table `id` is the playground id and is unique and `u_id`  is the user of the playground.

In **inspection** table `id` is unique and `playground_id` is used as a foreign key from **playgrounds** table's id.

My problem is that I have to pass `id` and `u_id` to the the query in **playgrounds** table then it should select id from playground table. Then it should select every thing from **inspection** table based on that id .

Hope I have explained it properly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: make a join on `playground_id`

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` operations, whether `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, or `RIGHT JOIN`, have this overall syntax.

```
   table_expression JOIN table_expression ON boolean_expression
```

When the Boolean expression is true, the `JOIN` concatenates the matching rows of the two tables into a single row in the result.

In your case, you want the ON clause's Boolean expression to say

```
  Playgrounds.id = Inspection.playground_id
```

because that's how you know a row from `Inspection` relates to a row in `Playgrounds`.  Accordingly, a statement like

```
 SELECT Inspection.id AS Inspection_ID,
        Playgrounds.id AS Playground_ID,
        Playgrounds.u_id AS User_ID
   FROM Playgrounds
   JOIN Inspection ON Playgrounds.id = Inspection.playground_id
  WHERE Playgrounds.u_id = something
    AND Playgrounds.id = something_else
```

See how it goes? Your `SELECT` makes a new table, sometimes called a result set, by JOINing the rows of two existing tables on the criteria you choose in the `ON` clause.

You can put anything you want into the `ON` clause.  You could put

```
Playgrounds.id = Inspection.playground_id OR Inspection.id < 20
```

or

```
Playgrounds.id = Inspection.playground_id OR Inspection.scope = 'citywide'
```

for example (if you had a `scope` column in the `Inspection` table).

But, don't go there until you master the basic `JOIN` operation.